# Rational functions serie

Tags: functions, arithmetic, rational-functions

I've stumbled upon an interesting question about rational functions I can't answer. What follows is given: 
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x} $$
$$ x_1 = \frac{1}{a}, x_2 = f(x_1), x_3 = f(x_2), x_4 = f(x_3), ..., x_{23} = f(x_{22}), x_{24} = f(x_{23}) = 1$$
What is $a$ equal to? How can you compute this? (There is a solution!)
Some context: it comes from a math Olympiad. I tried just filling it in, but there should be an easier way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was lazy, I should compute the first terms which give the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a-1},\frac{1}{a-2},\frac{1}{a-3},\frac{1}{a-4},\frac{1
   }{a-5},\cdots\right\}$$ and the pattern is clear.

If I was not lazy, I should solve the recurrence relation
$$x_{n+1}=\frac {x_n} {1-x_n} \qquad \qquad x_1=\frac 1a$$ the solution of which is simple (I let you finding it).

So $a=24$

Comment: You say "the solution of which is simple", but I don't get it... Woops. Can you please help solve me the recurrence relation/Write it out? I think I'll understand it then.

Comment: @PrincepsMaximus. Now, it is your turn ! I answered the question. Answer mine ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I can turn it into an explicit formula, because it has an easy structure. But I've (so far) never solved any recurrence relation nor did differentiation. However, I think I could learn a lot by seeing the methods I've searched for on Google applied to this example. Or could you at least refer to a good source for learning this? Thanks ;)!